# change navigator.notification.confirm Background color (White to Black)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm making Native App(for Android , IOS, BB10 && BB7) Using

`jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css`

`jquery-1.8.3.min.js`

`jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js`
 and 
`cordova.js` in my Application.

My code Looks Like

```
<!--My Script Tag Code-->
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", loaded, false);
function loaded(){
alert("device is ready");
}
  function MamWorkDone(){
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit ?", onConfirm, "RoomsTonite", "Yes,No");
    function onConfirm(button) {
    }
  }
</script>


<!--My Html5 Code Looks like-->

 <body> 
  <div data-role="page">

      <div data-role="header" >
         <h1>Page Title</h1>
      </div>   <!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content"> 
         <a href="#" data-role="button" id="btn_id" data-inline="true" onclick="MamWorkDone();" >Clear the Code</a>
      </div>   <!-- /content -->

      <div data-role="footer">
         <h4>Page Footer</h4>
      </div>   <!-- /footer -->
  </div>   <!-- /page -->

  </body>
```

this code able to show confirm dialog which is look like[image]

Here My Confirm dialog is Coming in White Background But I want This Confirm dialog in Black Background and Text Color White rather then black?
Please help me to resolve this issue?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess we can not change the background and text as it is the default for specific platforms. Like for Android it is looking like this and for iOS it will look different.

So to make customize alert box you can use jAlert or jquery mobile popup.

http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/02/22/jalert-jquery-alert-box-plugin/

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/

Comment: Thank you Sourav. I know dialog(alert) is showing by default by specific platform But I Really need to customize them.I check all possibility as you suggest but this didn't help me.